# Quotes in scripts results in “unterminated quoted string”

Tags: docker, composer-php, sh

I'm trying to use scripts of Composer with quotes to pass an environment variable to the command that will be run with Docker.

I use `sh -c 'A=b [command]'` in order to run a command with an environment variable.

Here is a minimal example:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "docker-run": "docker run --tty composer:2",
    "docker-version": "@docker-run composer --version",
    "docker-version2": "@docker-run sh -c 'CONSTANT=6.2.x-dev composer --version'"
  }
}
```

When I run it, the script `docker-version` works as expected:

```bash
$ composer run-script docker-version
> docker run --tty composer:2 'composer' '--version'
Composer version 2.3.10 2022-07-13 15:48:23
```

But the script `docker-version2` fails. The simple quotes are escaped and it breaks the command:

```bash
$ composer run-script docker-version2
> docker run --tty composer:2 'sh' '-c' ''\''CONSTANT=6.2.x-dev' 'composer' '--version'\'''
composer: line 0: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
Script docker run --tty composer:2 handling the docker-run event returned with error code 2
Script @docker-run sh -c 'CONSTANT=6.2.x-dev composer --version' was called via docker-version2
```

Comment: Issue was raised on Composer Discussions: https://github.com/composer/composer/discussions/10969

Comment: `"@docker-run env CONSTANT=6.2.x-dev composer --version"` ? `"@docker-run sh -c \"CONSTANT=6.2.x-dev composer --version\""`?

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks for your comment, it looks like it works. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: Both of them work?

Comment: Only the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set environment variables with `env` command.

```
docker-run env CONSTANT=6.2.x-dev composer --version
```